# Trying to access mapped api data and show it in React-big-calendar (ReactJS)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-big-calendar

I am trying to show data from api on react-big-calendar but can't seem to get the events to show up. I have mapped the data to a html table element. How should I use the mapped data to see the events in react-big-calendar?

Here is my code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Calendar, momentLocalizer} from 'react-big-calendar'
import moment from 'moment';
import 'react-big-calendar/lib/css/react-big-calendar.css';

export default function TrainingCalendar() {
    const localizer = momentLocalizer(moment)
    const [trainings, setTrainings] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
      getTrainings()
    });

    const getTrainings = () => {
      fetch('https://customerrest.herokuapp.com/gettrainings')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => setTrainings(data))
        .catch(err => console.error(err))
        console.log('trainings:',trainings);
    }

    const eventList = trainings.map((training) => 
      <tr key={training.id}>
        <td>{training.activity}</td>
        <td>{training.date}</td>
        <td>{training.duration}</td>
        <td>{training.customer.firstname}</td>
      </tr>
    );

    console.log('events:', eventList);

    const events = [
      {
        allDay: 'false',
        title: eventList.activity,
        start: eventList.date,
        end: eventList.date + moment().add(eventList.duration, 'minutes')
      }
  ];

    return (
        <Calendar 
        localizer={localizer}
        events={events}
        startAccessor='start'
        endAccessor='end'
        views={['month', 'day', 'week']}
        style={{height: 450}}
        />)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Events should be an Array of Objects with each training in your case. You don't need to create a table, instead of that you should map your trainings array to match the Calendar events way.

Like this:

```
Event {
  title: string,
  start: Date,
  end: Date,
  allDay?: boolean
  resource?: any,
}
```

In your case events would be something like:

```
    const events= trainings.map((appointment)=>{
              return {
                id: training.id,
                title: training.activity,
                start: new Date(training.date),
                end: new Date(training.date),
                allDay: false
              }
            })
```

Hope it helps you!